# Natural gas grill: is it ok to install the Quick Disconnect plug pointing up?

Tags: plumbing, gas, natural-gas

I bought a NG grill. The gas stub in my deck is pointing up. The grill's instructions manual says that the Quick Disconnect plug should be installed pointing down or sideways to avoid having water or debris fall in.

My thinking is that when I'm using the grill, I'll have the grill's gas hose plugged in. And when I'm not using it, I'll be covering it with the plastic cap that came with the Quick Disconnect plug. So it'll always be covered.  So does it really matter if it's pointing up?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will certainly get condensation inside, cap or no cap. And sometimes you'll likely forget the cap. It'll be expensive to repair your burner once it's rusted or clogged. Anyway, won't you be leaving the disconnect plugged in almost all the time, except when you want to move the grill away?

Why not just add two 90 degree elbows and a short connecting horizontal to give you a downward-facing opening for your quick connect?

Comment: I would get condensation regardless of the orientation of the gas stub right?  Or are you saying I would only get it if it was pointing up?  Right, the plan is that during the summer, the quick disconnect is plugged in.  And for the rest of the year, I'll have the cap on.  Given that I'm only doing it once a year, I don't think I'll forget the cap.  I guess the reason is the more joints, the more chances of a leak or issues.  If there is no benefit, then I'd rather just keep it simple

Comment: Any water that collects in the upward-facing end will not flow/drip out as it would in the other orientations. Joints are not an issue -- this is hundred+ - year old technology. I don't think the grill manufacturer would have mentioned it if there were no benefit, but it's obviously your setup and decision. Either way, enjoy the grilling!

Comment: I think I'm confused.  If it's covered, then how would water collect? I mean if I forget to cover it, then for sure.  It seems like there aren't any additional issues beyond stuff could fall in and get trapped.  Let me think about it.